# <play> No matter if it is Human or Machine Answered

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I want Twilio to dial a service that needs to provide an extension before it can leave a message.
ifMachine seems to wait for the "beep" , however there is a welcome message as soon as the call is placed: 
- Call Placed (Initiated + Answered)
- The recipient service plays : enter the extension of the mailbox you want to reach
- Twilio plays the digits of the extension
- Another message explanation message (about 20sec) is played
- Then the beep comes and twilio is suppose to play the mp3 to leave it in the mailbox.
I tried all day to get this to work.

Here is the php:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create('+18777777777', '5555555555', 'http://domain.com/play.xml', array(
    'Method' => 'GET',
    'FallbackMethod' => 'GET',
    'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',
    'IfMachine' => 'Continue',
    'Record' => 'false',
));
```

Here is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play digits="ww1900"></Play>
    <Pause length="25"/>
    <Play>http://domain.com/18.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

The call is placed, but lasts only 5 seconds, twilio does not continue.

Comment: Your xml is fine assuming is served with the right content type. Check the logs at Twilio for more detail about the error.

Comment: It might be worth trying to [record the call](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-record-a-phone-call-with-twilio) to see how far it gets too. Are you sure the call is waiting long enough when entering the extension?

Comment: Thank you for both your comments - The logs on Twilio are not showing anything else than completed. The duration is 5 secs .. with the xml above it should not be less than 25secs.

Comment: Thanks to philnash: I did record the call and I found out that .. I was not pointing to the right XML. Thank you guys for your insights. Big Help to debug this thing.

Comment: Michel, so glad you got it working! Do you mind putting your fix in an answer?